# C++11 Thread-safe polymorphism with less verbosity

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I am writing a logger and would like to make it thread-safe. I have done so by doing the following:

```
class Logger
{
public:
    virtual ~Logger();

    LogSeverity GetSeverity() const;
    void SetSeverity(LogSeverity s);
protected:
    std::mutex mutex;
private:
    LogSeverity severity;
};

void Logger::SetSeverity(LogSeverity s)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    severity = s;
}

LogSeverity Logger::GetSeverity() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    return severity;
}

void Logger::SetSeverity(LogSeverity s) const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    severity = s;
}

// StreamLogger inherits from Logger

void StreamLogger::SetStream(ostream* s)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    stream = s;
}

ostream* StreamLogger::GetStream() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    return stream;
}
```

However, all public access to the class require this extremely redundant lock.

Two options I see:

1) Caller of these public function will lock the whole object using the mutex within the class

```
Logger l = new Logger();
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(l->lock());
l->SetSeverity(LogDebug);
```

2) Wrapper lock around each variable in the class

```
template typename<T> struct synchronized
{
public:    
    synchronized=(const T &val);
    // etc..
private:
    std::mutex lock;
    T v;
};

class Logger
{
private:
    synchronized<LogSeverity> severity;
};
```

However, this solution is very resource intensive, lock for each item.

Am I on the right track or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why can't you set the stream and the severity in the constructor?

Comment: The constructor will assign sane defaults (std::cout, LogCritical) and the public methods allow user to change them. It's a usability decision, I'm afraid lumping it into the constructor to rid the problem won't do me any good.

Comment: @cvicci, Agree with Chris. I think you should reconsider your use cases. Usually, you can set things done during construction or likewise in the main thread, before other threads are spawned. Then you don't need any lock for those setters/getters.

Comment: @EricZ Understood, however, I will encounter a problem in my constructor where it will take more and more parameters and eventually become something like StreamLogger(LogSeverity severity, string format, ostream stream, ...more options). I'm not understanding my bad design decision?

Comment: As an aside, it might help to group the mutexes by, well, mutual exclusivity. It's safe for threads to access a stream and a severity at the same time, right? That would actually lead to more efficient use than having the user lock the whole object to do anything.

Comment: @cvicci It's not this "static polymorphism" that thread is invented. If you need customization of the class, you should take a look at design pattern(e.g., factory pattern or strategy pattern may suit the need).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to carefully reconsider possible use cases:

- do you really need logger to be so configurable?
- what properties can be initialized during construction?
- does it make sense to change all of them?

I have a strange feeling, that you think about your classes in a very small perspective: "well, it's a logger, so I will put all **possibly** useful features into it" (I may be wrong). Classes should have complete, but minimal interfaces, explicitly representing what particular class is responsible for. Think about that.

As for your multi-threading problem: I don't think shared logger is a good idea. *Personally*, I always prefer thread-specific primitives in such cases (one logger per thread). Why?

- if logger writes to a section of memory, you only need to lock *block of memory*, not logger itself
- if logger writes to a file, your task is even simpler - remember, that OS manages file access, so you don't need to worry about two loggers writing to the same section of the same file (you must design your logger to ensure that, but it's really not that hard)
- bonus: different threads may write to different outputs if necessary

If your compiler supports C++ 11, above solution is basically proper usage of [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local), [`__declspec(thread)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb.aspx) or [`__thread`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Thread-Local.html), depending on what your compiler supports.

If you **still** want to implement shared logger, start from design review. For example: are you sure, that changing single property requires locking a mutex? Things like `severity` member is perfect candidate for [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). It may require more work, but can be **much** faster.

```
class Logger
{
    //cut

private:
    std::atomic<LogSeverity> severity;
};

void Logger::SetSeverity(LogSeverity s)
{
    severity.store(s, std::memory_order_release);
}

LogSeverity Logger::GetSeverity() const
{
    return severity.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
}
```

`std::memory_order_acquire/release` is just an example - you may want to use stronger ordering like `memory_order_seq_cst` (if you need total global ordering). However `acquire/release` pair is usually enough to ensure proper synchronization between loads and stores and small bonus - they will not produce any fences on x86.

If think you might want to read `C++ Concurrency in Action` by Anthony Williams. It is the best resource for learning threads, atomics, synchronization, memory orderings and more.

There is also a very good articles on [Bartosz Milewski's blog](http://bartoszmilewski.com/). Like this one: [C++ atomics and memory ordering](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/01/c-atomics-and-memory-ordering/) .

If you are not familiar with topics like atomics, fences, orderings etc., these resources are very good to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume it's reasonable of your requirement to access these setters and getters in different threads.

I may be wrong. But from the limited code you've shown, the way you lock these members is just wrong. It's not that simple just to lock the paired setter and getter. Consider this:

```
void tYourClass::thread_1()
{
   ..
   m_streamLogger.SetStream(/*new stream*/);   
}

void tYourClass::thread_2()
{
   ostream *stream = m_streamLogger.GetStream();
   // access the returned stream
   // stream->whatever()
}
```

In this case, right between you get the stream handle and access it, another thread kicks in and set the stream. What will happen? You get a "**dangling**" stream: you may access a deleted object, or log something that will never be seen by others(depending on the logic inside `SetStream`). Your lock just failed to protect it. The root cause is that you should lock the statements which are supposed to be executed as a single "atomic" procedure where no other thread can kick in before its completion.

And I have two suggestions.

1. Don't put any lock inside setters/getters. This is either because it cannot protect everything as said above, or because of efficiency. You may like to invoke these methods in the same thread. If that's the case, you don't need any lock. Generally, setters and getters themselves can't(and shouldn't) realize how they will be accessed. So a more reasonable place is to put the lock in the client code where you think multithreading is really involved.
2. Don't try to protect anything with a single lock. A lock is supposed to be held as short as possible. If you overuse a single lock for lots of independent resources, the degree of concurrency(one primary benefit of thread) will be compromised.

Comment: That's not really a lock issue at heart, is it? He'd have that problem with one thread and the calls being sequential.

Answer (score 0):

First,  I question if you really need those setters. The easiest way to make a class thread safe is to make it immutable.

Even if you did make them thread "safe", do you really want one thread changing the destination stream while another thread is in the middle of logging messages?

In this case it looks like you could simply set the severity and steam in the constructor:

```
StreamLogger(LogSeverity severity, ostream& steam);
```

If the number of constructor arguments becomes unmanageable you could create a builder or factory or just group your arguments into one object:

```
StreamLogger(const StreamLoggerArgs& arguments);
```

Alternatively, you could separate out the parts of logger that really need to be thread safe into an interface.  For example:

```
class Logger {
  protected:
    ~Logger(){};
  public:
    virtual void log(const char* message) = 0;
    virtual LogSeverity GetSeverity() const = 0;
};
```

And that is the interface you pass to multiple threads, the concrete implementation can still have setters (not necessarily thread-safe) if you like, but they are only used from one thread when the object is first set up.